# scrjura and tex4ht: issue with headings

Tags: tex4ht, html, scrjura

The scrjura.sty is part of the KOMA-script bundle. I'm using it to draft contracts.

Often I have to deliver a word file. So I'm using tex4ht to produce it from my *.tex file. Let's say, the name of the tex-file is contract.tex, this MWE:

```
\documentclass[pagesize, ngerman, fontsize=12pt, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel, scrjura}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{microtype}

\title{Sicherheitsbestellung}
\subtitle{gag}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{contract}
  \Clause{title=Eine Paragraphenüberschrift}
  \label{CLA:erster-Par}

  Dieser Paragraph hat nur einen Absatz und der Text ist kurz.

  \Clause{title=Zweite Überschrift}
\label{CLA:titl-uberschr}

Dieser Paragraph hat zwei Absätze, dieser Satz hier ist der erste.

Und hier haben wir den zweiten Absatz. 

\end{contract}


\end{document}
```

Then I call tex4ht:

```
htlatex contract.tex "scrjura" " -cunihtf"
```

A friendly soul wrote `scrjura.cfg` years ago, it is a small file:

```
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter

\Preamble{html,charset=utf-8}

\begin{document} 

\def\qtchr{\expandafter\@gobble\string\"}
\
\ConfigureList{contract}
  {\HCode{<div class=\qtchr contract\qtchr>}}
  {\HCode{</div>}}
  {}{}

\append:def\contract@paragraph@font{\a:contract@paragraph@font} 
\append:def\contract@paragraph@font{\b:contract@paragraph@font} 

\NewConfigure{contract@paragraph@font}{2}
\Configure{contract@paragraph@font}
  {\HCode{<div class=\qtchr paragraph\qtchr>}}
  {\Tg</div>}

 \pend:def\parformat{\a:parformat} 
 \append:def\parformat{\b:parformat} 

 \NewConfigure{parformat}{2}
 \Configure{parformat}
   {\EndP\HCode{<p class=\qtchr para\qtchr>
    <span class=\qtchr sentence\qtchr>}}
   {\Tg</span>}

 \Css{.sentence{margin-left:2em; padding-top: .5em;}}
 \Css{.paragraph{margin: 1em;}}
 \Css{.para{margin: .5em;}}

\EndPreamble 

\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother

\endinput
```

The trouble is: If a clause only consists of the heading and one paragraph, there is no `\par` between heading and text. This screenshot is taken from the contract.html:

[image: Image displaying two clauses]

The usage of the words paragraph in the German text is confusing, just ignore it.

Question: How to change scrjura.cfg to get a `\par` between heading and paragraph, even if the clause only consists of a heading and one paragraph.

You need to know one thing: If a clause only has one paragraph, `scrjura.sty` does not enumerate it. If a clause has more than one paragraph, they get numbers.

I really hope I have described my wish clearly. If in doubt, please ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file in the MWE hooks to `parformat` in order to insert `<p>` and `<span>` tags that create the paragraphs on the html page. `parformat` (which prints the sentence number) is not used for a single-sentence paragraph and therefore the html tags are not inserted in this case.

A possible solution would be to hook to `\Clause` or to `\par` but this is left as an exercise (i.e. I have no clue how to do that).

A workaround is to slightly modify `scrjura.sty` to call `parformat` in all cases. To keep the current output (no number for single sentences) the definition of `parformat` itself should also be modified to display an argument, allowing it to be called with an empty argument for single sentences and with the sentence number for multiple sentences.

When `parformat` is modified the use of the argument must be indicated in `scrjura.cfg`, by using `defI` instead of `def`.

MWE:

`scrjura.sty`

```
\newcommand*{\parformat}[1]{#1} % was: \newcommand*{\parformat}{(\thepar)}
[...]
\ifnum \@tempcnta>\@ne    %at the end of \newcommand*{\contract@everypar}
    {\usekomafont{parnumber}{\parformat{(\thepar)}\nobreakspace}}% % modified %
\else
  \def\reserved@a{\relax}%
  \ifx\@tempa\reserved@a
    \parformat{}% % modified/added (originally empty clause) %
  \else
    {\usekomafont{parnumber}{\parformat{(\thepar)}\nobreakspace}}% % modified %
  \fi
\fi
```

`scrjura.cfg`

```
[...]
\pend:defI\parformat{\a:parformat} 
\append:defI\parformat{\b:parformat} 
[...]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works! I'll ask the maintainer if he could adapt scrjura without side effects. And maybe Michal H. has an idea, too...